# Xcopy does not copy files when run from c#

Tags: c#, batch-file

I start the .bat file from c# code:

```
     void ExecuteCommand(string command)
     {
        var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command);
        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        var process = Process.Start(processInfo);

        process.OutputDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
            Console.WriteLine("output>>" + e.Data);
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();

        process.ErrorDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
            Console.WriteLine("error>>" + e.Data);
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();

        process.WaitForExit();

        Console.WriteLine("ExitCode: {0}", process.ExitCode);
        process.Close();
    }
```

It starts, everything gets executed, but the:

```
set mydir = "C:\mydir"
xcopy /c /y "myFile.exe" %mydir%
```

the file is not copied

But when I run the same batch file from explorer, the file gets copied. Any thoughts?

Comment: Incorrect %mydir% value after a Process.Start?

Comment: `"C:\mydir` is a strange `targetdir`, too...

Comment: Two possible things: (a) you're setting `targetdir` but using `mydir` - is this right? and (b) is `myFile.exe` the name of the C# exe, because if it is, it may be "in use" when the program is running.

Comment: This was a mistake, the clue is that the same bat executed from double click or command line copies the files, but executed from code, writes the echo lines, but the files are not copied.

Comment: The myFile.exe is not a c# exe, it is another file

Comment: have you used the debugger..? try changing the target directory to have the `@` for example pass the following and try it 
`var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + @command);` also make sure that the directory has a `"\"` at the end otherwise you're probably trying to copy a file to a file name with the directory as part of the name vs copy to Directory + `"\"` + filename in .net `set mydir = "C:\mydir"` the single `"\"` is seen as a return character

Comment: You do not specify where myFile.exe is, hence it will only work if your startup folder is set to the correct folder.

Comment: XCopy.exe is very quirky when you redirect, if its output is redirected then its input must be redirected as well.  If it isn't then it fails to get the job done without any diagnostic.  Not sure if that is still the case when you redirect Cmd.exe.  Simply try it, set processInfo.RedirectStandardInput to *true* as well.

Comment: Hans Passant, RedirectStandartInput worked for me ! thanks

Answer (score 5):

Adding processInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true; worked for me - now files are copied without issues